# regex does not match only upper case letters, despite being instructed to do so

Tags: python, regex

I'm making a script to crawl through a web page and find all upper case names, equalling a number (ex. `DUP_NB_FUNC=8`). The part where my regular expression has to match *only* upper case letters however, does not seem to be working properly.

```
value = re.findall(r"[A-Z0-9_]*(?==\d).{2,}", input)
```

```
|tc_apb_conf_00.v:-:DUP_NB_FUNC=2

|:-:DUP_NB_FUNC=2

|:-:DUP_NB_FUNC=4

|:-:DUP_NB_FUNC=5

|tc_apb_conf_01.v:-:DUP_NB_FUNC=8
```

Desired output should look something like the above. However, I am getting:

```
|tc_apb_conf_00.v:-:=1" name="viewport"/>

|:-:DUP_NB_FUNC=2

|:-:DUP_NB_FUNC=4

|:-:DUP_NB_FUNC=5

|tc_apb_conf_01.v:-:DUP_NB_FUNC=8
```

Based on the input I can see its finding a match starting at `=1`. I don't however understand why as I've put only `A-Z` in the regex range. I'd really appreciate a bit of assistance and clearing up.

Comment: Could it be that you allow zero `[A-Z0-9_]`s? Does `[A-Z0-9_]+` make a difference?

Comment: Regex 101 can potentially explain what is happening with your expression more clearly. https://regex101.com/r/qE8iQ7/1  - The issue it seems is the ".{2,}" which matches any letter (besides newline) unlimited times. I imagine if you put anything else after the `=<digit>` it would match that as well. Or change the `*` to `+` to match between `1 and unlimited` times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be help:

```
[A-Z0-9_]+(?==\d).{2,}
```

or

```
\b[A-Z0-9_]*(?==\d).{2,}\b
```

But anyway your regex quite weird, according to your requirement above I suggest this

```
[A-Z0-9_]+=\d+
```

Instead of using

`(?==\d).{2,}`: any letters two or more and make sure that the first two letter are `=` and a one integer respectively,

you can just use

```
=\d+
```

Comment: @Milen Markkov If its still not correct please add more information and data that we can use to test it according to your request.

Comment: Ok, sorry for not clearing that up previously - the reason im using {2.} is because further down the string there are series of 20+ parameters tied to one .v module (not just one parameter as in my example) and im trying to catch the entire series , in my opinion if i dont use the {2.} it just matches the first one and continues on

Comment: @MilenMarkov where your regex is end then if end at the end of the line you should place `$`.

Comment: @MilenMarkov Any one of my regex is correct? If not I think you suppose to add more information that related to your problem.

Comment: thank you, adding replacing * with a + did the job nicely. But i still dont understand why does it match lower case letters to a [A-Z0-9] range? or is that because in '=1" name="viewport"' it just matches the number disregarding the rest ?

Comment: @MilenMarkov `*` stands for zero or more, consider you regex `[A-Z0-9_]*(?==\d).{2,}`, In case `*` is zero your regex become `(?==\d).{2,}` now your regex can match any text that begins with `=\d` according to `(?=...)` and follow by any characters according to `.{2,}`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. 
`value = re.findall(r"[A-Z0-9_]+(?==\d).{2,}", input)`

You want the case sensitive match to match at least **once**, which means you want the `+` quantifier, not the `*` quantifier, that matches between **zero** and unlimited times.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you define your pattern and check you input if it is available

for i in tlist:
    value=re.compile(r"[A-Z0-9_:-.]+=\d+")
    jee=value.match(i)
    if jee is not None:
        print i

tlist contains your input